# How to edit ony the mute part of an audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to make some effects like

**[Original]** aacdb[mute 5s]ksaihnx[mute 12s]aidhsjd

=>**[New]**aacdb[mute 10s]ksaihnx[mute 24s]aidhsjd

you see only the mute part changed(twice), the other kept stable.
Or

**[Original]** aacdb[mute 5s]ksaihnx[mute 12s]aidhsjd

=>**[New]**aacdbaacdb[mute 5s]ksaihnxksaihnx[mute 12s]aidhsjdaidhsjd

here we repeat each one sentence(twice).

Also is there any choice in ffmpeg such that I could only edit some certain part?
For example, only stretch the mute part(set it less than 100（db）).

Comment: I'm not going to say you _can't_ do this in ffmpeg, but it's certainly not the tool I would reach for. (Personally, I'd start with Reaper -- not Free Software but very cheap, with excellent cross-platform support and an active community developing plugins in javascript; _those plugins_ are mostly open source, and provide a lot of examples on where to start).

Comment: Anyhow -- to have an on-topic Stack Overflow question, you're going to want to start by getting to the point where you've written enough code that you actually have a narrow, specific problem with that code.

Comment: (...honestly, you could probably do this yourself, in Python, using numpy to manipulate your sound file as a big array of numbers, which is effectively what it is; no need for ffmpeg _or_ REAPER or such at all).

Comment: I don't have a worked code for this question, for example ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mp3 will edit the WHOLE audio but I only want to edit the CERTAIN part.

Comment: but does python really work here? I know python could only use ffmpeg in it, I am not familiar...expert.

Comment: You need to convert away from mp3 into an array of individual samples, but once you've done that, yes, you can absolutely use Python to directly edit your waveforms, no ffmpeg use needed.

Comment: f/e, https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/how-to-io.html#read-an-arbitrarily-formatted-binary-file-binary-blob shows an example of how to read a wav file in numpy (wav being an example of an uncompressed format, ready for editing).

Comment: it broadens my horizon!

Comment: but some people recommend pydub to do it. And my audio is not wav but mp3